# qsort() an array of graph structures

Tags: c, qsort

```
struct Edge
{
    int src, dest, weight;
}; typedef struct Edge Edge;

struct Graph
{
    int V, E;
    Edge* edge;
}; typedef struct Graph Graph;
```

I have a graph struct like this. I am trying to use qsort to sort all the edges in increasing order of their weight.
in main:

```
Graph* graph = (Graph*)malloc(sizeof(Graph));
qsort(graph->edge, graph->E, sizeof(graph->edge[0]), myComp);
```

Mycomp function:

```
    int myComp(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    Edge* a1 = (Edge*)a;
    Edge* b1 = (Edge*)b;
    return a1->weight > b1->weight;
}
```

After all, I tried to print every edge before and after the qsort, the order has been changed but it is not the correct order. Anyone can help with these? What part is wrong in my code?

Comment: [**Don't** cast the return value of `malloc`!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: ... in C. :-)

Comment: @alk …which this question is about.

Comment: As the code stands there is nothing to sort, `graph->edge` points nowhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return a1->weight > b1->weight;
```

should be

```
return a1->weight - b1->weight;
```

From the manual:

> The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

Comment: Jesus. just have it fixed. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to add to the answer by @n.m.

However you can compactify your declarations a bit if you write

```
typedef struct Edge
{
    int src, dest, weight;
} Edge;
```

or even

```
typedef struct
{
    int src, dest, weight;
} Edge;
```

if you plan to use a type-def'd name `Edge` only and will not need an explicit name of the basic type `struct Edge`.